# Setting seekbar value as value

Tags: android

Okay, so I have an app where you can pick the color and size of a brush, and draw on the screen. I have buttons to choose the color, and a seekbar to change the brush width. The problem is that every time I choose a new color, I have to define a brush width, so every time a color is chosen, you have to use the slider again to pick the size.

Currently I have my seekbar called `SeekBar`, and then I have this code every time I select a new color:

```
currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
```

How could I replace the 3 with whatever value the seekbar is at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(seekBar.getProgress());
```

also make sure you set a maximum value for the seekBar:

```
seekBar.setMax(10);
```